# JavaScript: loop with a while

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I learn at the Codecademy, and now I face with such issue: site say me "Are you logging 'I'm looping!' to the console three times?" ,but I can't get it over. Please,help me.

There is code:

```
var loop = function()
{
    var x = 0 ;
while(x)
{
        while(x<3)
        {
            console.log("I'm looping!");
            x+=1;                       
        }
        x+=1;
}
};
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having, specifically.  Also, why do you have two `while` loops?

Comment: What happens when the `while(x)` line is first evaluated? Is `x` truthy or falsey?

Comment: Thank you, just as I have already said - in this case, I had to learn how to better use "while".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting x to zero, which evaluates to false in a condition.

```
while(0)
```

is essentially equal to

```
while(false)
```

which will never run.

Change your code to this

```
var loop = function()
{
    var x = 1;
while(x)
{

    while(x<=3)
    {
        console.log("I'm looping!");
        x+=1;                       
    }
    x-=1;
}
};
```

You also have a bunch of unnecessary code. You could shorten it to simply:

```
while(x<3){
    console.log("I'm looping!");
    x++;
}
```

or simply

```
for(x=0;x<3;x++){
  console.log("I'm looping");
}
```

Comment: @plalx, in the first example `x` starts at 1. And before an edit, it was looping `while (x < 3)`. So 1, 2, and then breaking at 3.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful! But the only thing that I changed on another it's "x-=4".

Comment: Of course, to be fair, just realized now that it will actually print "I'm looping!" infinite times. The inner loop breaks at `x = 4`, then subtracts 1, making it 3 again, so it will come back to the inner loop, print, increment x, break out, decrement x, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Now need for the double `while` loop, in fact, this seems like a case for a `for` loop, but you can use a `while`

```
var x = 0;
while(x<3)
{
    console.log("I'm looping!");
    x+=1;                       
}
```

Or with a `for` loop, since you know the limit:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    console.log("I'm looping!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know but in this case me should use "while" to learn how use it.

Answer (score 0):

This will print "I am logging" three times using a while statement.

```
var x = 0;
while (x < 3) {
    console.log("I am logging.");
    x += 1;
}
```